# Getting Invalid field definition error when trying to link Access 2010 to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, ms-access-2010

I am trying to link a table from an Oracle database in Access 2010. I have been successful with three other tables but this last one gives me the error - Invalid field definition'{field Name}' in definition of index or relationship.

The field name is IGNORESRMAVAIL

Column Name     ID      PK   Null?    Data Type   Default      Histogram   Num Distinct

IGNORESRMAVAIL  324     N   NUMBER      null    Frequency   2

Constraints in Oracle:

SYS_C00120249   Check   Enabled     Not Deferrable  Immediate   Validated           1   "IGNORESRMAVAIL" IS NOT NULL

Indexes:

DE_WORKORDER_NDX32  N   YES 1   IGNORESRMAVAIL  Asc 2

Any Help would be very very much appreciated

Thanks
Gary

Comment: Did you ever figure out what caused this? I'm having a similar issue. I think it's related to an encrypted field.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with a SQL Server back end. I realize that the OP was having issues with Oracle, but there are no other answers at this time, and maybe our solution will help the next guy.

In my case, I ran into an issue with a VarBinary(256) field; giving the same error as OP.

Microsoft has a hotfix that I think might fix this, but I was not able to install it on my work machine.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2459110

What I actually did to resolve the issue was create a view that did not include the VarBinary field. Worked like a charm.